# why is Json parsing breaking While loop?

Tags: python, json, parsing, beautifulsoup

I am trying to create a program that would text me anytime ethereum prices change by a decent amount. In order to do  this i have a while loop continuously parsing and grabbing the information. However it will give me the information three times and then give me the error:

```
change = json.loads(soup.select_one('script#server-app-state').contents[0])
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'contents'
```

My code:

```
import json
import time
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
normalprice = True
URL = 'https://www.coinbase.com/price/ethereum'

while normalprice:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(URL).content, "html.parser")
    change = json.loads(soup.select_one('script#server-app-state').contents[0]) 
    BDP = change['initialData']['data']['prices']['prices']['latestPrice']['percentChange']['day']
    BRV = round(BDP * 100, 2)
    print (BRV,'%')
```

Comment: Because on that occasion `select_one('script#server-app-state')` returned None, and calling `.contents` on None raised an exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting a "CAPTCHA" page because you're making too many requests too quickly. Put `time.sleep()` in your loop and `try..except` around the `json.loads`.

For example:

```
import json
import time
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


normalprice = True
URL = 'https://www.coinbase.com/price/ethereum'

while normalprice:
    time.sleep(3)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(URL).content, "html.parser")
    try:
        change = json.loads(soup.select_one('script#server-app-state').contents[0])
    except:
        print('-')
        continue
    BDP = change['initialData']['data']['prices']['prices']['latestPrice']['percentChange']['day']
    BRV = round(BDP * 100, 2)
    print (BRV,'%')
```

Prints:

```
-2.21 %
-2.21 %
-2.21 %
-
-
-
-
-2.21 %
-2.21 %
-2.21 %
-

... and so on.
```